# Sacar el porcentaje de eficiencia

Tags: excel, vba

necesito sacar el porcentaje para sacar un promedio de eficiencia, que consiste en:

Ejemplo:

Durante 75 días, una persona debe entregar 50 informes, solo entrega 30, le restan 20.

Como seria la formula para sacar el porcentaje de eficiencia. Intento con esta fórmula pero no obtengo el resultado deseado:

=(P8/P7)*Q6-P6

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como tal debería dar un porcentaje superior al 50% ya que entrego mas de la mitad de los informes que debía en los 75 días

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Es una regla de 3 simple ; si 50 es el 100% ; entonces 30 es el x%

Comment: ¿Quienes son `P8`, `P7`, `P6` y `Q6`? La fórmula que muestras, ¿qué se supone que hace? Saludos

Comment: lo que necesito es que la formula me calcule el porcentaje de cuanta eficiencia tuvo alguien respecto a los informes que debia entregar en 75 dias. Como especifico en la imagen de ejemplo.
- 50 Es la cantidad de informe que es el 100%
- 30 es la cantidad de informe que entrego
- 20 es la cantidad que falta por entregar
- 75 son los días en que se tenían que entregar

P8, P7, P6 Y Q6 son las celdas

Comment: actualice la imagen para que se entienda mejor

Answer (score 0):

En tu ejemplo das los datos de los días pero no explicas cómo influye en el cálculo.

Si los días no influyen, simplemente divide Cantidad entre entregado y aplica formato porcentaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi formula en C3 es `=B2/B1`

Ahora bien, si te influye el tiempo, edita tu pregunta y explica cómo lo influye. Entiendo que entregar las 50 unidades en 75 días es 100% de eficacia. ¿si lo entregase en la mitad de tiempo, sería un 200%? Eso no lo has puesto en tu pregunta.